# Integrity constraint violation when tring to make a payment: 1062 Duplicate entry xxx for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID'

Tags: magento2

After the migration of new orders from Magento 1 to Magento 2 I find the following error when trying to make a payment.

Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1200022450-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_order` (`state`, `status`, `protect_code`, `shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`, `base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`, `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`, `base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`, `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`, `store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`, `total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`, `customer_group_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`, `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `base_total_due`, `shipping_discount_amount`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `total_due`, `weight`, `increment_id`, `applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`, `customer_email`, `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`, `customer_middlename`, `discount_description`, `global_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `remote_ip`, `shipping_method`, `store_currency_code`, `store_name`, `total_item_count`, `discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amount`, `base_shipping_discount_tax_compensation_amnt`, `shipping_incl_tax`, `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `gift_message_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) in /

Answer (score 0):

Just re-index the database and it should fix the issue.

```
php -d bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```